# Insert batch to MySQL with PHP/PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, bulkinsert

I have an form for bulk add domains and these domains could have one or more countries and one language attribute.

My form (reduced to code):

**Add domains:**

```
<textarea name="bulk" rows="10" class="form-control no-resize"><?php echo $_POST['bulk']; ?></textarea>
```

**Choose one or more countries:**

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <?php
  if ($queries->query("SELECT * FROM countrycodes ORDER BY code ASC")) {
    if ($queries->count() > 0) {
      $contents = $queries->fetchAll();
      foreach ($contents as $content) {
  ?>
  <input type="checkbox" id="country_<?php echo $content->code; ?>" name="country[]" value="<?php echo $content->code; ?>" <?php if (in_array($content->code, $_POST['country'])) echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?> />
  <label for="country_<?php echo $content->code; ?>"><?php echo $content->country; ?></label><br />
  <?php }}} ?>
</div>
```

**Choose the language:**

```
<div class="radio">
<?php
if ($queries->query("SELECT * FROM langcodes ORDER BY code ASC")) {
  if ($queries->count() > 0) {
    $contents = $queries->fetchAll();
    foreach ($contents as $content) {
?>
<input type="radio" name="lang" id="lang_<?php echo $content->code; ?>" value="<?php echo $content->code; ?>" <?php if ($content->code == $_POST['lang']) { ?>checked="" <?php } ?> />
<label for="lang_<?php echo $content->code; ?>"><?php echo $content->language; ?></label><br />
<?php }}} ?>
</div>
```

**Get data from submit:**

```
if (isset($_POST['addData'])) {
  $doms = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST['bulk']));
  $coun = implode(", ", $_POST['country']);
  $lang = $_POST['lang'];
}
```

I found this one for bulk inserts:

```
$d    = ['Osian', 'Williams', 1];
$data = array_fill(0, 1000, $d);
$db   = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MYDB','MYUSER','MYPASS');
$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (firstname, surname, title) VALUES (?,?,?)');
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
  $stmt->execute($data[$i]);
}
$db->commit();
```

I have no idea, how to get my data (domains, countries, lang) working for this code.

And, I need to check if a domain is already in the db, but only, if the domain has the same language.

So, would be nice to get some help.

Comment: Read https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp, once you submit your form, the action page will get the entered values in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array. Write your business logic in the action page.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution. Was a bit confused at the beginning, how to add country and lang to the list of domains. But the country data and lang data are static - so I just need to loop through the domains.

That's my solution and it works:

```
if (isset($_POST['addData'])) {
  $doms = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST['bulk']));
  $coun = implode(", ", $_POST['country']);
  $lang = $_POST['lang'];

  $queries->transStart();
  foreach ($doms as $dom) {
    if ($queries->query("SELECT domain FROM websites WHERE domain = ? AND lang = ?", [$dom, $lang])) {
      if ($queries->count() > 0) {
        $infoBox = "error_duplicate";
      } else {
        $queries->query("INSERT INTO websites (domain, country, lang) VALUES (?,?,?)", [$dom, $coun, $lang]);
        $infoBox = "success";
      }
    }
  }
  $queries->transStop();
}
```